# Custom Workflow Activity ReferenceTargetAttribute for User OR Queue

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

In Dynamics CRM 2013 I want the input parameter of a workflow activity to be similar to the `From` Lookup on an E-Mail which allows looking up a `User` or a `Queue`.

I've tried using `activityparty`, but it does not work.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to define an input parameter that accepts a `User`

```cs
    [Input("FromEmail")]
    [ReferenceTarget("systemuser")]
    public InArgument<EntityReference> FromEmailRecipient{ get; set; }
```

Comment: the code is right, just an advice: input parameters can accept only 1 entity type (so systemuser or queue) it's not possible to make them accept more than one entity type.

Comment: Yeah this doesn't handle what I want since its just systemuser.  I think I'll just have to get the entity's logical name and id as two separate parameters.